# How To Prevent \ Showing Up Next To Quotation Marks?

Tags: php, mysqli, escaping, sql-injection

My script has it so a user will enter in text, it will go into a MariaDB database and then come back out in the screen to simplify it. However, when a user enters `'` or `"` it will go to the database as `\'` or `\"`. I assume this is to prevent a MySQL injection attack but is there any way to prevent it from coming back on the screen escaped? My simplified code is

```
//$con is the connection
<?php
$msg = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['message']));
$insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `db` (message) values(?)");
$insert->bind_param("s", $message);
$insert->execute();
```

and then it will print it out on the screen from reading the database normally, nothing weird or unexpected.

Comment: Using `mysqli_real_escape_string` is useless, as prepared statement does the same thing.

Comment: You're using a prepared statement. This is a Good Thing™, so you don't need to escape the data first. You shouldn't ever be using `htmlentities()` on data you're sending to the database. It's for output to the browser.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular you should make that an answer